# Making lists lowercase issue

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to make my roles in the list case-sensitive so when the command **Blue** is invoked in can be invoked either as **Blue or blue** the error I get from my code is:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`

The particular line where the error occurs `if Colours.lower() in role:`

This is how my code looks.

```
#--- Role list Categories ---"
    Colours = ['blue', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Black']
    Games = ['LoL', 'WoW']
    Platforms = ['PC', 'Xbox', 'PS4', 'Nintendo Switch']

    if ctx.message.channel == intros:
        pass
    else:
        if ctx.message.channel == botroom:
            message = '\n**Colour Roles** \n__Change the colour of your nickname.__\n'.format(author.display_name)
            for role in Colours:
                if Colours.lower() in roles: # if the command is typed cases-sensitive 
                    message += '\n{} **({})**'.format(role, len([member for member in guild.members if ([r for r in member.roles if r.name == role])]))
                    message += ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A python list has no `lower()` method. Try instead:

```
for role in [c.lower() for c in Colours]:
    if role in roles:
```

Comment: This seems to have helped me out `role.capitalize()`

Answer (score 0):

This line here:

`if Colours.lower() in roles:`

is trying to lowercase the list `Colours`.  you should try:

`if role.lower() in roles:`

since `role` goes through each string in the list of Colours.

Comment: I did try this unfortunately it removes the role from the roles list `Colours = ['Blue', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Black']`  Though if I  changed the colour **Blue** to **blue** in the list it will show up when the command !list in invoked. I assume this is because I typed it case sensitive in the list.  However I want the user to be able to use either both Blue or blue.